# Azure Database Backup lost Comment

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, database-backups, bacpac

I am using the DAC framework's [Import Export Service Client tool](http://sqldacexamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/87880) to export a BACPAC file from a SQL Database on Azure. But when I restore the BACPAC file to the Azure Database, it **loses the comment** of a Store Procedure or a View, which was initially entered **above the Create statement**. Is this because of the export tool neglecting comments outside of the Create View or Store Procedure?

```
/*  
 XXXX Procedure    
 Version 1.0,   */
 CREATE Procedure [dbo].XXXX
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with DAC. But I think this is an expected behavior. Comments are not used at runtime. If they’re removed, performance can be slightly improved as the engine doesn’t need to parse the comment.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.